# How to make authors' emails associated with their institute?

Tags: titles, lncs

I try to make my institute followed directly with my email and my boss institute followed directly with his email. I have the following code. However, I still get our institutes first then followed by our emails?

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{url}
\urldef{\mailsa}\path|myemail@uni.ac.uk|
\urldef{\mailsb}\path|{myboss}@uni.ac.uk|
\urldef{\mailsc}\path||
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\par\addvspace\baselineskip
\noindent\keywordname\enspace\ignorespaces#1}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter  % start of an individual contribution

% first the title is needed
\title{Title}

% a short form should be given in case it is too long for the running head
\titlerunning{title}

% the name(s) of the author(s) follow(s) next
%
\author{me\inst{1,2} \and myboss\inst{2}}
%
\authorrunning{}
% (feature abused for this document to repeat the title also on left hand pages)

\institute{my institute, my boss institute\\
\mailsa\\
\mailsb\\
\mailsc\\
}
```

I need it in the PDF file to become as follows:

```
My name, boss name
My institute
My email
boss institute
boss email
```

Comment: I do not know the `llncs` documentclass. But many of the commands you use (e.g. `\inst{}`, `\institute{}`) are not defined in your code, so I assume they are defined within the documentclass. This in turn would mean that the formatting it gives you is probably how things **should** be formatted in that documentclass!? If you don't like it, I would say use a standard class and do it yourself as you want to have it. Then again, you probably use that class because you have to, in which case you probably should not mess with its formatting!!???

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solve it. Thank you for people who react with my question. The code is running well by changing the    \mailsa\ location as follows:

```
\institute{My institute
\\
\mailsa\\
\and My boss institute\\
\mailsb\\
\mailsc\\
}
```